# Error building tensorflow C++ shared library on windows

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake

I am trying to build tensorflow as a standalone project and have been following this tutorial

http://www.stefanseibert.com/2017/10/tensorflow-as-dll-into-your-windows-c-project-with-gpu-support-and-cmake-v1-3/

but alternatively with cpu support

My environment setup versions

**protobuf**            3.6.1
**tensorflow**          1.10.0
**tf.GIT_VERSION** = b'v1.10.0-rc1-19-g656e7a2b34'

Here are the steps I used to generate the shared lib

1. Acquired source code from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
2. Have installed the dependencies since I do not use the python bindings, there is no need for SWIG, so I installed Git (version 2.15.1.windows.2) and cmake 3.11.1
3. I used the 64bit tools from Visual Studio 2015 since VS2015 is necessary to build the DLL. I should be able to open the “VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt”. This is needed so VS uses the 64 bit toolset.
4. Navigated in the commandline to the “tensorflow/contrib/cmake” subfolder of the source code and create a directory with “mkdir build”. Afterwards navigate to the fresh build folder with “cd build”.
5. Create a build solution: cmake .. -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo   -Dtensorflow_BUILD_CC_EXAMPLE=OFF -Dtensorflow_ENABLE_GRPC_SUPPORT=OFF -Dtensorflow_BUILD_CC_TESTS=OFF -Dtensorflow_BUILD_PYTHON_TESTS=OFF -Dtensorflow_ENABLE_GPU=OFF  -Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:AVX -Dtensorflow_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=ON
6. Everything went fine till this. To build the tensorflow.dll, I issued the following command: MSBuild /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo tensorflow.vcxproj
7. This throws an error: **D:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow/core/lib/core/stringpiece.h(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'absl/strings/string_view.h': No such file or directory (
   compiling source file D:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\lib\core\coding.cc) [D:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_lib.vcxproj]**.
8. I fixed the above error with this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22007#issuecomment-424553600.
9. Doing the above I ended up with this error: **path.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl absl::base_internal::ThrowStdOutOfRange(char const *)" (?ThrowStdOutOfRange@base_internal@absl@@YA
   XPEBD@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl tensorflow::io::internal::JoinPathIm**

I am not able to proceed further. Any workaround for this? Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, `string_view` is a C++17 feature.  Make sure you are running `Visual Studio 2015 Update 3` or possibly even the latest version of VS2017.

Comment: @JamesPoag [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) is a C++17 feature, but what the compiler is complaining about is that it cannot find the headers, and the link the library, for [Abseil](https://abseil.io/) (which polyfills the feature for previous standards).

Comment: The TensorFlow team is dropping support for CMake building. According to the release notes, this was officially done in [v1.11.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.11.0), but it was first announced in [v1.10.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.10.0), I am not sure if just as a warning or because they actually started there... I do not know how to solve your issue, but I have been able to build a TF dll (actually a custom wrapper dll including TF) with Bazel on Windows, in case you want to consider that path.

Comment: Thanks @jdehesa Do you have the steps to create TF dll with Bazel on windows?

Comment: @NagamaniNagaraj More or less... I created a simplified wrapper because I'm not sure how to collect all the headers for a hypotetical `tensorflow.dll` (and anyway it would be too many and my wrapper has two). Mostly you follow the setup from [Build from source on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows), but instead of building `//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` I added my own target that depends on `//tensorflow/core:tensorflow` marked with [`linkshared`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary.linkshared).

Comment: @NagamaniNagaraj Oh and I pass `--config monolithic` to `bazel build`, not sure if that is still necessary or if it is the default option but just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your help @jdehesa I am not familiar with bazel so I couldn't generate .dll. I tried with many things and messed up.

Comment: @NagamaniNagaraj You may be interested to know, there is a C TensorFlow lib for integration, see [Install TensorFlow for C](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c). Although it's not officially announced for Windows, you can find builds in https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow, e.g. for v1.11.0 CPU there is https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.11.0.zip . Docs are in the header and some of the API seems still not stable but it should be usable. Also there is no `.lib`? But you can google how to generate it from the DLL...

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for your help. As you said, there were not much APIs. I need to have a tensorflow.lib / .dll  which should enable me to create sessions and run the sessions. To be more specific, https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f I need to run the c++ program by linking tensorflow.lib/.dll in this link

Answer (score 1):

lnk2019 error occurs when your directly you are using in your source code are not linked properly. Please add additional dependencies to your project.

- Going to project properties
- select C/C++ option
- Add aditional dependencies
- Go to Linker Option Below C/C++
- Add additional Dependencies here.

It might be help full for you from getting out to LNK2019 problem

[view this to understand LNK2019 error.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/799kze2z(v=vs.140))

Answer (score 0):

I met same issue, I think tensorflow new version doesn't support CMake, but we can solve the issues.
1. Seems the absl version in project folder is out dated, so I cloned the latest version of abseil-cpp from: https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp
2. Use cmake to build the abseil-cpp, it will be fast.
3. Add lib path to tensorflow dependency, the needed one will be D:\git\abseil-cpp\abseil-cpp\build\absl\base\Release\absl_absl_throw_delegate.lib
4. If you meet other linking error, you can find the function name in absl sources and find the library contain it.
Hope this can help you and people who may met this issue in future.